# How to create a database partitioned by year using DolphinDB Python API?

Tags: python, dolphindb

I want to create a partitioned database based on year using DolphinDB Python API. Here is my script:

```
def create_database(self) :

self.partition_value_array = np.array(pd.date_range(start = "20141231", end = "20241201", freq = "Y"), dtype="datetime64[D]") 

self.current_database_path = "dfs://database_1"
self.current_database_name = "dfs_database_1"
    
if self.current_session.existsDatabase(self.current_database_path) :

self.current_session.dropDatabase(self.current_database_path)   

self.current_dfs_database = self.current_session.database(dbName =  self.current_database_name, partitionType = ddb.settings.VALUE, partitions = self.partition_value_array, dbPath = self.current_database_path)
```

But the created database is actually partitioned by day. How can I modify this script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the `VALUE` partition type automatically expands the partitions based on the date values, which results in date-based partitions. To create a database partitioned by year, you can refer to the following script:

```
yearRange = np.array(pd.date_range(start='2011-01-01', periods=10, freq='12M'), dtype="datetime64[M]")
db = s.database(dbName='mydb', partitionType=keys.RANGE, partitions=yearRange, dbPath="dfs://testdb")
```